# Python custom iterator: iteration over non-sequence

Tags: python, iterator

I'm trying to create an iterator that extracts every word from a text file and iterates through them. This is what I have right now:

```
class String_iterator:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.words = []
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            self.words.extend(line.split(" "))
        self.ind = 0
        self.size = len(self.words)

    def __iter_(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.ind > self.size:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.ind += 1
            return self.words[self.ind-1]
```

Comparing it to functional simple examples of Python iterators, I can't figure out why it isn't working when I try to use it in even a simple case:

```
sit = String_iterator(filename)
for word in sit:
    print word
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WordCounter.py", line 68, in <module>
    for word in sit:
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

I am guessing that there is something wrong with the `String_iterator` that it's not a proper iterator, but I can't figure out what.

(I'm also having issues with the encoding on reading in the file, but that's another issue altogether...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot an underscore:

```
def __iter_(self):
# ---------^
```

Python won't recognise your custom class as an iterator unless you use the correct name:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self
```

Comment: Wow.  I feel really stupid now.  But thanks.